# MVC archt. in Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller

I want to implement MVC arch. in silverlight application.

I have the following questions:

Is silverlight version and MVC architecture is dependent? for example: silverlight 4 is required for building the silverlight mvc application

Can any one give any example or sample project link or code, so that i can refer for building my own?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Silverlight there is more common to use MVVM architecture then MVC. SL has some features that allows easily use MVVM in it.

Useful links:

- [Model-View-ViewModel In Silverlight 2 App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458800.aspx)s
- [Using the MVVM Pattern in Silverlight Applications](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/silverlight-4/using-the-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-applications/)
- [Good Silverlight-MVVM Practice Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413451/good-silverlight-mvvm-practice-example)
- [5 Minute Overview of MVVM in Silverlight](http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/5-minute-overview-of-mvvm-in-silverlight/)